# Treemap with variable # of categories (Plotly)

Tags: python, pandas, colors, plotly-python, treemap

I am working on a dashboard that uses a dataset for a treemap that looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

col1 = ['United States','Mexico','Canada','Argentina','France','Portugal','Italy','Spain','Brazil','Peru']
col2 = [4,6,6,9,10,3,20,15,16,2]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'country': col1,
    'count': col2
})
```

I will be using a filter that will change the countries and counts.  Here is some code that will produce the treemap:

```
tree_fig = px.treemap(
    df, 
    path = ['country'],
    values = 'count',
    template='plotly_dark',
    color = 'country',
    color_discrete_map={
        df['country'][0]: '#626ffb', 
        df['country'][1]: '#b064fc', 
        df['country'][2]: '#ef563b',
        df['country'][3]: '#f45498',
        df['country'][4]: '#ff94fc',
        df['country'][5]: '#a8f064',
        df['country'][6]: '#24cce6',
        df['country'][7]: '#ffa45c',
        df['country'][8]: '#00cc96',
        df['country'][9]: '#fff000'

    }   
)
tree_fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate='Count=%{value}'
)
tree_fig.show()
```

This all works, but when using the filters there will be situations where I have fewer than 10 countries in the dataframe.  How can I rewrite the `color_discrete_map` argument to account for a varying number of categories.

Comment: are we assuming that there will be at most 10, but perhaps less than 10? or can it be larger?

Comment: 10 is the max # of categories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
# create a function which creates colour maps
def colour_map_creator(df, col):
    colour_map = {}
    for i in range(len(df[col])):
        colour_map[df[col][i]] = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[i]
    return colour_map
```

Then replace the dictionary which is the value of `color_discrete_map` with  `color_map_creator(df, 'country')`.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use a dictionary with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
colors = ['#626ffb', '#b064fc', '#ef563b', '#f45498', '#ff94fc',
          '#a8f064', '#24cce6', '#ffa45c', '#00cc96', '#fff000']

# px.treemap(...
color_discrete_map=dict(zip(df['country'].unique(), colors))
# ...)
```

Output:

[image]

Or using `px.colors.qualitative.Plotly` like in @Mark's answer:

```
# ...
color_discrete_map=dict(zip(df['country'].unique(), px.colors.qualitative.Plotly))
# ...
```

Output:

[image]

Intermediate:

```
dict(zip(df['country'].unique(), px.colors.qualitative.Plotly))

{'United States': '#636EFA',
 'Mexico': '#EF553B',
 'Canada': '#00CC96',
 'Argentina': '#AB63FA',
 'France': '#FFA15A',
 'Portugal': '#19D3F3',
 'Italy': '#FF6692',
 'Spain': '#B6E880',
 'Brazil': '#FF97FF',
 'Peru': '#FECB52'}
```

Also note that if you want to use specific colors but do not care about a specific mapping, you can use:

```
colors = ['#626ffb', '#b064fc', '#ef563b', '#f45498', '#ff94fc',
          '#a8f064', '#24cce6', '#ffa45c', '#00cc96', '#fff000']

# px.treemap(...
color_discrete_sequence=colors
# ...)
```